# Written Semicha Tests

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, semicha

Which Rabbonim give a semicha based on a written test (as opposed to requiring one to complete a program under them)? 
Are they only on Basar Bechalav and Ta'aruvos, only on Shabbos, only on Niddah or on all three?

Comment: Rav Nechemia Goldberg,I am assuming Rabbanut

Comment: There is no advantage one way or the other,some semichas are looked upon better then others irrelevant if its harder or not,

Comment: Pirchei Shoshanim is a very hard semicha program(written tests) but it is not as famous as other semichas

Comment: "only on Basar Bechalav, only on Shabbos, only on Niddah or on all three"? Doesn't standard _s'micha_ include also _taaruvos_?

Comment: Yes. I edited to reflect that

Comment: You forgot melicha which is standard as well

Comment: No, melicha is not necessarily standard. The program that I attend and several like it leave it out, although the Rabbanut and many other programs include it.