# Semicha Testing Info

Tags: semicha

I know that most Semicha Tests cover (aprox.) the laws of Basar B’Chalav, Ta’aruvos, Melicha, Shabbos, Pas Akum, Bishul Akum, Cholov Akum, and Tevilas Keilim.

But is it tested all in one shot or do they break it up ie. melicha and only afterwords Basar Vechalav.

Comment: Different programs for different yeshivos.

Comment: @user6591 what do most do?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15796/759

Comment: From what I've heard most have a test at the end of each subject matter. But many have even less subjects than you mentioned. Bassar bichalav, taarovos and Melicha are a semicha program by themselves in many yeshivos.

Comment: Some yeshivas include Niddah for semicha.

Comment: Pas Akum, Bishul Akum, Cholov Akum, and Tevilas Keilim... are not usualy tested seperaty (they are ~ small)

Comment: Some places test on everything in one shot and it is a very long exam

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35315

Comment: @Yez and/or Mikvaot, Avelut, and Siddur Kiddushin.